# Complexity of Algorithm,when while loop changes

Tags: algorithm, code-complexity

This algorithm gets array as a input.

```
i=1
j=1
m=0
c=0
while i<=|A|
   if A[i] == A[j]
      c=c+1
   j=j+1
   if j>|A|
     if c>m
       m=c
     c=0
     i=i+1
     j=i
return m
```

As i know, while loop's complexity is O(n). But I can't understand this algorithm and while loop. I need to know how does this algorithm's complexity calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop iterates on the *i* value, but it can perform several iterations with the same value. A secondary variable *j* is then incremented instead, and it runs up to the same maximum value.

This means that in fact this algorithm loops for every [(unordered) combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of 2 values (*i* and *j*) from the given array *A* (including twice the same value). For example, if *A* is [1, 2, 3, 4], then *i* and *j* take these values per iteration of the `while` loop:

```
  i  |  j
-----+-----
  1  |  1
  1  |  2
  1  |  3
  1  |  4
  2  |  2
  2  |  3
  2  |  4
  3  |  3
  3  |  4
  4  |  4
```

If we define *n* as the number of values in *A*, then the `while` loop iterates *n(n+1)/2* times. In the example above: 4*5/2 = 10 times.

This is *½n²+½n* = *O(n²)*.

Note that the manipulation of the variables *c* and *m* in the code does not influence the time complexity, only the outcome of the function.

Comment: I want to ask a question about calculating values. When we go into while(i<=|A|). Should i think like it is i<= A[0] ? What does it do?

Comment: It is pseudo code, so there is no syntax definition, but the vertical bar symbol is probably used here as denoting the size of *A*, so it is a test to see that *i* is still an index in the array, and not beyond it.

Comment: ok now i got it. I've found all values of variables except 1,1(i,j). Could you please explain how we get it? Isn't j=2 when we give "1" value to i variable?

Comment: Your code initialises both variables to 1 in your question, so the first iteration of the `while` loop starts with these values. To be clear: the table of values I presented is the situation at the *start* of each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The slowest process decides the time taken in any process.

Understand this with an example;
I want to buy a car and a bicycle.
The price of a car is around $100000 and that of bicycle is $1000
When I add them I got this as $101000
A question arises here; What decides the cost of both?
Of course the car is the deciding factor. We would often ignore the price of bicycle in this case.

Time taken in a loop is more than that of declaring some variable or some arithmetic operation as this loop might run billion times.

```
i=1
j=1
m=0
c=0
```

This part will take one unit of time.

While, this entire code -->

```
while i<=|A|
   if A[i] == A[j]
      c=c+1
   j=j+1
   if j>|A|
     if c>m
       m=c
     c=0
     i=i+1
     j=i
```

will run N number of times where N is length of your array.

Similarly those assignments and conditional operations will take O(1) time.

Adding them gives you

O(1) + O(N)= O(N) //{ Remember the addition of car and bicycle}

Comment: What is *N* in your answer?

Comment: N is the number of times the loop will run. In this case the length of the array.

Comment: Then your answer is wrong: *i* does not increment each iteration. Check my answer.

Comment: Oh. My bad I didn't noticed. I answered about the general case. Sorry for that